# Is it possible to notify Firebase Cloud Message (previous GCM) that device is already online?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FCM for an IM application. Everything works fine when all devices are on a good internet connection, however, there is a particular situation that is causing the UX to become poor.

When the device is connected to an access point (either a wi-fi network or mobile network) but, for some reason, packages don't make to the device (weak signal or poor connection, lets say edge or 3G, and sometimes even on wi-fi).

By default FCM queues all pushes and resend them to device once it becomes online again. This is where things get complicated. I think that the event that tells FCM that the device is online is NetworkStateChanged. The problem is, in the scenario described above, the network state doesn't change, only the truly ability to delivery the packages, hence, it takes forever for FCM server identify that the device is back online - I know that it is online 'cause other calls to my AppServer happens successfully.

**So my question: is there a way to "ping" FCM and notify that the device is online?**

Comment: So basically, you want the client app to send a message to the FCM server. Kinda like an Upstream message. Wouldn't that make use of a [XMPP Protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref)? Not sure though. Just came to mind.

Comment: Not quite that. I don't want to send an upstream message, I just wanted to accelerate the process of acknowledge that the client application has come back online again. The default process takes too long to realize that - I assume because it relies on NetworkStateChanged to do so, which isn't good enough for the situation I've described in the question